# GWTP Handlers are Thread safe?

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I am using gwt-platform for my application development.

I opened 2 browsers running the same application, i did 2 same operations with different data, but the now the browsers on the same view accessing the similar handler action

now the issue is the 2 browsers has updated with first received data from handler..

i am not understanding why it is not recognized the browsers which send the request... so this means its not Threadsafe...?

I seen @RequestedScope annotation in the Guice is it useful when i use on execute() of Handler

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

You have to made your Actions thread-safe. (attrs has final, e.g., inject in constructor), and perharps your logic has to be thread-safe too.

Btw, can you post a example of your action?

Answer (score 1):

With 2 browsers you should have 2 different instances of your app running. In your `onModuleLoad()`, just put a `System.out.println(this);`. You should see different result which means you have different instances.

If you run an action from Browser 1, the action will be executed **only** in Browser 1. I don't know what your action is doing but if it updates data in the datastore (or DB) and since both instances share the persistence layer, you will see the new data in Browser 2 too.

It's very unlikely that the action triggered in Browser 1 is executed on both Browsers. It would mean that they share the same event bus.

Comment: may be it might be sharing the same bus event.. how can i find that instance of event bus which it is going thru... as per gwt-platform it is application level only.. can you elaborate this point thanks

Comment: In your presenter, the event should be injected. Just call a `System.out.println(eventBus)` to see the instance. Are you sure that the action is called twice. To make sure put a trace in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InfoAction extends UnsecuredActionImpl<Response<ObjectTO>>
{   
    private List<OpenTO> request;
    private String machineId;
    private int actionType;
    private UserBean userBean;

    /**
     * This is been in the case of double dated flight.
     */
    private String orignalFpesLegId;

    public List<OpenTO> getRequest() {
        return request;
    }

    public void setRequest(List<OpenTO> request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public String getMachineId() {
        return machineId;
    }

    public void setMachineId(String machineId) {
        this.machineId = machineId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the actionType
     */
    public int getActionType() {
        return actionType;
    }

    /**
     * @param actionType the actionType to set
     */
    public void setActionType(int actionType) {
        this.actionType = actionType;
    }

    /**
     * @param userBean the userBean to set
     */
    public void setUserBean(UserBean userBean) {
        this.userBean = userBean;
    }

    /**
     * @return the userBean
     */
    public UserBean getUserBean() {
        return userBean;
    }
}
```

Please find my action class code